# SciPy Medfilt returning only 0 values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Hi I'm working on a code that calculates the median values for a given window size in my data set. I'm using medfilt from SciPy. I don't understand why the median array returned is all zeroes. I've changed the kernel size but that didn't affect anything, and I'm wondering if the shape of my array affects medfilt. Here is my code:

```
    from __future__ import division
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import scipy as sp
    from scipy import signal

    filename = "hbond.txt"
    hbond_val = []
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            f_line = np.array(line.split())
            hbond_val.append(f_line)
    bond_array = np.asarray(hbond_val)
    bond_array_float = bond_array.astype(float)
    bond_1d = np.reshape(bond_array_float,50001)
    #print bond_1d.shape
    median = sp.signal.medfilt(bond_array_float,101)
    #plt.plot(range(len(bond_array)),bond_array,'b')
    #plt.plot(range(len(median)),median,'r')
    #plt.show()
    print median #median returns array full of zeros
```

Comment: You created `bond_1d`, but you used `bond_array_float` in the call to `medfilt`.  What is the shape of `bond_array_float`?  I suspect is it two-dimensional, and the length of one of the dimensions is small (well, significantly smaller that 101).

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I didn't realize I forgot to change it!!